# TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "filter") to list

Tags: python, jupyter, conda

How can I fix this error?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-4e1a4ac4ce1b> in <module>()
----> 1 j = NJoin(R, S)
      2 render_markdown(j)
      3 print(get_result(j))

/Users/mona/CS460_660/relation_algebra.py in __init__(self, op1, op2)
    164         self.common = s1.intersection(s2)
    165         self.op_str = "$\Join_{{{0}}}$".format(','.join(self.common))
--> 166         OpBase.__init__(self, op1.schema + filter(lambda x : x not in self.common, op2.schema), [op1,op2])
    167         self.count_reads = True
    168 

TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "filter") to list
```

Here's the entire `relation_algebra.py` file:
https://pastebin.com/Nwuddb77

I have created a py27 virtual environment using conda create because authors have suggested to use Python2.7 not Python3.6 as in https://github.com/HazyResearch/cs145-notebooks-2016/tree/master/lecture-16 
When I execute this cell from the jupyter notebook I get the above error:
I get no other error in other cells before that
[image]

I had the same exact error when I was running the code with Python 3.6 as well:
https://github.com/HazyResearch/cs145-notebooks-2016/issues/4

Comment: Trying adding list() around the filter

Comment: which line? only  OpBase.__init__(self, op1.schema + filter(lambda x : x not in self.common, op2.schema), [op1,op2]) ?

Comment: @Avery246813579 is suggesting `list(filter(...))` (which will fix your problem)

Comment: Yup. If it fixes it I will post it as an answer to others can find the answer if they have the same problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirming that changing following line:

```
OpBase.__init__(self, op1.schema + filter(lambda x : x not in self.common, op2.schema), [op1,op2])
```

to:

```
OpBase.__init__(self, op1.schema + list(filter(lambda x : x not in self.common, op2.schema)), [op1,op2])
```

Fixed the problem.